# add class when click on a div

Tags: jquery, sidebar

I'm trying to make a sidebar with a navigation menu that will expand/collapse when I click on a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {     
$('.btn-nav').click(function(){     
    $('.sidebar').addClass('expand');    
},     
function(){    
    $('.sidebar').removeClass('collapse');     
});
});
```

When I replace the click function to a hover function it works fine. But now it won't work. Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Click takes one function, not two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.btn-nav').click(function () {
        $('.sidebar').toggleClass('expand').toggleClass('collapse');
    });
});
```

If you have a look at the [click() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/click/), you will find that it takes only one function but the [hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) takes one or two handlers function, executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

Comment: or `$('.sidebar').toggleClass('expand collapse');`

Answer (score 0):

Click event doesn't have a parameter. You can use the below code,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var testMethod = function(event){
        if(event.data.flg == 0){
             $('.sidebar').addClass('expand');
             event.data.flg=1;
        }
        else {
            $('.sidebar').removeClass('collapse'); 
            event.data.flg=0;
        }
    };


    $('.btn-nav').on('click', {flg: 0}, testMethod);
});
```